# set static variable in function only once

Tags: c++, eigen

So I was wondering if it is possible to set a static variable inside a function scope only once. For example consider this function:

```
void projectPointIntoPlane(const Affine3f& plane2xy, Vector3f& p)
{ 
  static Matrix3f P;
  P << Vector3f::UnitX(), Vector3f::UnitY(), Vector3f::Zero();

  p = plane2xy.inverse() * P * plane2xy * p;
}
```

I would like to set P only once and not at every function call, how can I achive this?

Comment: I was going to upvote....but then I noticed your rep was 0xff.....jk  +1

Comment: not sure what you mean...

Comment: You had exactly 255 reputation before I upvoted

Answer (score 8):

Instead of declaring `P` and thereafter initializing it separately, you can initialize it in the declaration, using the [`finished()` method of `CommaInitializer`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1CommaInitializer.html):

```
static const Matrix3f P =
    (Matrix3f() << Vector3f::UnitX(), Vector3f::UnitY(),
     Vector3f::Zero()).finished();
```

With this approach, you can also declare `P` as `const`.

Comment: to me this looks way cleaner than what igor or rakete propose, but it is not so general...

Comment: @user3726947 indeed, this would be the idiomatic Eigen approach. If I didn't know this was Eigen (and did not have access to the fit-for-purpose `finished()` method) and would need general solution, Igor Tandetnik's lambda is a good approach.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a lambda that returns the right value. Since it's in the initialization expression, it's only called once:

```
void projectPointIntoPlane(const Affine3f& plane2xy, Vector3f& p)
{
    static Matrix3f P = []{
        Matrix3f P;
        P << Vector3f::UnitX(), Vector3f::UnitY(), Vector3f::Zero();
        return P;
    }();

    p = plane2xy.inverse() * P * plane2xy * p;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines:

```
static Matrix3f P;
static bool dummy = (
  (P << Vector3f::UnitX(), Vector3f::UnitY(), Vector3f::Zero()),
  true);
```

Comment: Or fold the initialization in the lambda and then return the object.

Comment: I just noticed that at the moment this is more generic, if for example P is a template the lambda wont work.